# Why the function malloc can be used like this?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am reading the book "Expert C Programming", but here is the code that really confused me. I can't understand the use of the function malloc and the value it returns here, and why running this will return the memory allocated in the process? 
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int MB = 0;
    while(malloc(1<<20))  ++MB;
    printf("Allocated %d MB total\n",MB);
}
```

Comment: That runs until `malloc()` returns `NULL`, leaking memory like a sieve in the meantime. Probably the intent is to measure how much memory a program can allocate, but depending on OS and malloc implementation that might be very inaccurate or even a for-all-intents-and-purposes infinite loop.

Comment: I've got it running in another window.  Hasn't run out of memory yet.  (It's using 99% of one core, though.)

Comment: That book was written in 1994. A lot has changed since then. Try finding a book that was written within the last 10 years.

Comment: It ran for three minutes, and then the OS summarily killed it, presumably because it had used "too much" memory.  Based on other evidence, it seems to have achieved a virtual address size of something like 64800000 MB (that is, it made 64800000 trips through the loop, called `malloc` 64800000 times), and chewed up maybe 40% of the machine's memory.  So, yeah, agree with user3386109 that this particular experiment maybe isn't so useful any more.

Comment: @steve: linux, right? Search for "optimistic memory allocation". The memory "allocated" is irrelevant but malloc's internal datastructures and the kernel's page tables are for real.

Comment: Either that or his box has 64T of RAM.... `:)`

Comment: @rici Actually, it's MacOS (High Sierra), and it "only" has 16 GB of physical memory, so yes, it would appear there's a bit of "optimistic" memory allocation (or Apple's equivalent) going on.

Comment: @steve: i was just trying to figure out whether macos did optimistic allocation without access to a mac, so thanks for the confirmation. Even without optimistic allocation, malloc can succeed well beyond the ram capacity; reserved allocation only requires there to be backing store in case you actually use the memory. But i'll bet you don't have 64 terabytes of backing store either.

Comment: Anyway, the code in question embodies what in some circles is called the "Boogie 'til you puke" algorithm (with apologies to the late Root Boy Slim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<` operator does a bit-wise left shift. So this shifts binary 1 left by 20 positions.
i.e. 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 becomes 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000. 
This is equivalent to 1 MB since a MB is defined as 2^20.

Therefore each `malloc()` call tries to allocate 1 MB. `malloc()` will return NULL if it cannot allocate this much space. In C, NULL will evaluate to False.

Therefore, in each iteration of the loop, the program will allocate 1 MB. If it's successful, it increases the MB counter. If `malloc()` runs out of space, it will return NULL and end the loop. The `printf` statement will then print the amount of memory that was allocated.

Comment: But it might do something else.  On my machine it made over 64 million trips through the loop, "successfully" allocating something like 16 TB of memory (roughly 4000 times the machine's physical memory, and 64 times its disk space), before the OS killed it for being such a memory hog.  (This was MacOS, but Linux does something similar.)

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int
A = 1 << 0, //1         byte        2^0     0x00000001  0b00000000000000000000000000000001
B = 1 << 8, //256       byte        2^8     0x00000100  0b00000000000000000000000100000000
C = 1 << 10,//1024      byte 1KB    2^10    0x00000400  0b00000000000000000000010000000000  
D = 1 << 20,//1048576   byte 1MB    2^20    0x00100000  0b00000000000100000000000000000000
E = 1 << 28;//256 e6    byte 1GB/4  2^28    0x10000000  0b00010000000000000000000000000000


const int TOP = 100;//25GB max
void* p[TOP] = {};
for (int i = 0; i < TOP; i++)           //32 bit system max 2Gb
{
    p[i] = malloc(0x10000000);          //1GB/4  or 256Mb
    //p[i] = malloc(1<<28);
    //p[i] = malloc(E);

    printf("%4d 0x%08x\n", i, p[i]);        //32 bit system
    //printf("%4d 0x%016llx\n", i, p[i]);   //64 bit system
}
for (int i = 0; i < TOP; i++)
    free(p[i]);
```